# Set Checkbox Values to a Specific values

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, checkbox

i have a winform C# app that retrieves values from a sql server and has to store in the checkbox as text value. the user will check on the checkbox and save the corresponding value back to the table(This part is later on.)..
here is how my form looks like.
[image: form1]

Now, say for example, in my table it holds 12 subject e.g sub1, sub2...sub12.
there is no distinction in the table as to which subject belongs to which semester. 
herein lies my problem, i want to be able to get the subjects say for sem 1 and only display in the first 4 checkboxes, suppose there are subjects from sem 2 show them in the checkboxes in the fourth panel. 
i know i have to compare manually all the values, if they contain words like"sub1" if yes the check a checkbox. but there are too many variables here....

is there any way to solve my problem ?

Comment: too many variables? I think you need to use SQL to generate the "already-registered" page

Comment: Did you try to put all your variable in an array, so you just have to loop it and switch the values with a String.contains?